# Are lessons available for FlightSim X?

Tags: flight-training, flight-simulator

I have Flight Simulator 2008, and there were some really good lessons for student pilots.

Are there flight lessons in FlightSim X, either part of the software, or available from external sites?

The FSX Learning Center shows some, but it seems you can't use them.

Answer (score 3):

FSX has lessons. See the Learning centre.
You have to scroll through the text, and then you can fly some lessons.